# More issues connecting iOS portion of Flutter App to Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

In following [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup) to connect my Flutter app to Firebase, the guide says running the terminal command `open ios/Runner.xcworkspace` in the top level directory of my app, it should open in Xcode and look like this:

[image]

yet mine looks like this:

[image]

It would seem one or more of the members of the combination I'm using - Swift/Xcode 10/iOS 12/iPhone XS Max - is the source of the issue. Perhaps too cutting edge.

Is there a way to get this combination working or do I need to fall back to either Objective-C, iOS 11.4 (or 11.3) and/or iPhone X?

Comment: Simple, run pod install for you flutter ios application, then open it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tldr; Steps for connecting Flutter app using iPhone XS Max ios 12.1 simulator to Firebase. YMMV, use at your own risk.**

I was able to resolve my problem and get my Swift/Xcode 10/iOS 12/iPhone XS Max Flutter project to connect to Firebase, although it ended up being Swift/Xcode 10.1/iOS 12.1/iPhone XS Max. Since Firebase, Swift, Xcode, Cocoapods and RVM are interrelated/interdependent, I don't know exactly which thing, or combination of things I did, solved my problem, so I've outlined all of my steps so that if you are also having issues connecting to Firebase with a similar configuration, one or more of these steps may help resolve your issue.

1) Uninstalled existing Xcode app (and Xcode command line tools) by dragging `Applications/Xcode`, `~/Library/Developer/`, and `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode` to the trash. You may or may not have the last file depending upon the version of Xcode you have.

2) Uninstalled Cocoapods in the terminal using `brew uninstall cocoapods`. (Not needed if you installed Cocoapods using RVM rather than Homebrew)

3) Installed Xcode 10.1. Opened it to install additional tools. Ran `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`, `sudo xcodebuild -license` (paging down multiple times and entering "agree"), and `sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable`.

4) Installed Xcode 10.1 Command Line Tools.

5) Ran `rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles`. Bottom of my .zshrc file (possibly your .bashrc or .bash_profile file) looks like this (no other lines below):

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

6) Since I use zsh instead of bash, ran `source ~/.zshrc` to update current terminal session, then`rvm cleanup all`. Ran `echo $PATH` to verify that my desired gemset was the first entry in the path.
*(Update: The gemset is no longer the first entry in my path, but things are still running correctly. Not sure if this is critical for other things, but does not seem to impact this scenario.)*

7) Reinstalled Cocoapods with `gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.6.0.beta.2`.

8) Updated all gems with `gem update`.

9) Updated Homebrew, my formulae, and my casks with `brew update && brew upgrade && brew cleanup; brew doctor`.

10) Ran `pod setup`.

11) To set my Xcode simulator default device to "iPhone XS Max", ran `xcrun simctl list --json` to generate a list of the available simulator devices. Located UDID associated with the iPhone XS Max under "iOS 12.1", copied and pasted UUID into this command `xcrun simctl boot DB8E7F47-DD01-4952-9BE8-5BCEB6BDBDB0` and ran it.
*(Update: This step appears to no longer be necessary. When you open the iOS Simulator in the IntelliJ Idea project in Step 17 below, you should be able to choose a device by selecting "Hardware > Device > iOS 12.1 > iPhone XS Max" in iOS Simulator.)*

12) In IntelliJ Idea project, opened the `pubspec.yaml` file and added `firebase_core: ^0.2.5+1` as follows:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.2.5+1
```

then selected "Packages get" in the IntelliJ Idea IDE.

13) Followed Firebase Step 1 for adding iOS app to project, "Register App":

- Right-clicked `/ios/Runner` folder in IntelliJ Idea project
- Selected "Flutter > Open iOS module in Xcode"
- Clicked on "Runner" icon at top of left-hand panel
- In center panel, under "General" tab, copied the bundle identifier in the second line at the top under "Identity", which looked like "com.company.app". (If you're not seeing the "General" tab, click the "Runner" on the **second line** at the top of the center panel, not the one on the first line, and choose "Targets - Runner" from the dropdown instead of "Project - Runner".)
- Pasted bundle identifier in Firebase Step 1 input "Register app - iOS bundle ID"
- Leaving other inputs blank, clicked "Register app" button.

14) Followed Firebase Step 2:

- Downloaded `GoogleService-Info.plist` to desktop
- In Xcode (see note below), right-clicked **inner** Runner folder
  (left panel "Runner > Runner")
- Selected "Add Files to Runner..."
- Added the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file.

*Note: Originally downloaded `GoogleService-Info.plist` directly to `/ios/Runner` folder in IntelliJ project, but this caused an error, described and resolved [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16871). While, after completing Step 2, `GoogleService-Info.plist` **does** appear in the Runner folder in Xcode, it **does not** appear in `/ios/Runner` folder in the IntelliJ project. I'm not sure if this will create a future issue, but at the moment, it does not.*

15) Followed Firebase Step 3:

- In IntelliJ terminal, ran `cd ios` then `pod init`. (If you already have a Podfile, you can skip this step, although if things don't ultimately work correctly, you may want to come back to this step and generate a new Podfile.)
- Opened Podfile and uncommented "platform :ios" line at the top and changed value to '12.1'
- Still in Podfile, added `pod 'Firebase/Core'`

Snippet for Podfile code placement:

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
```

- Opened `project_name/ios/flutter/release.xconfig` and added the line `#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig"`
- Ran `pod install`

16) Followed Firebase Step 4:

- In Firebase app setup screen, copied `import Firebase` from Swift version of the `AppDelegate` initialization code
- Pasted into `project_name/ios/runner/AppDelegate.swift`
- In Firebase app setup screen, copied `FirebaseApp.configure()` from Swift version of the AppDelegate` initialization code
- Pasted into `project_name/ios/runner/AppDelegate.swift`

Snippet for AppDelegate.swift file code placement:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase                   //  <--

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

    FirebaseApp.configure()      //  <--

    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

17) In IntelliJ, selected "Open iOS Simulator" in the upper right dropdown. The iOS Simulator opened with the "iPhone XS". I changed the device in iOS Simulator with "Hardware > Device > iOS 12.1 > iPhone XS Max".

18) In IntelliJ terminal, ran "flutter doctor -v" and the following was output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.1.9, on Mac OS X 10.14.2 18C54, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.1.9 at /Users/my-macbookpro/flutter
    • Framework revision 1407091bfb (2 weeks ago), 2019-01-08 20:40:19 -0800
    • Engine revision e5ec3cf3ea
    • Dart version 2.1.1 (build 2.1.1-dev.0.1 2cb346bd0c)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/my-macbookpro/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/my-macbookpro/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.1, Build version 10B61
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4
    • CocoaPods version 1.6.0.beta.2

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 29.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 181.5656
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.3.4)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 31.3.4
    • Dart plugin version 183.5429.25

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone XS Max • DB8E7F47-DD01-4952-9BE8-5BCEB6BDBDB0 • ios • iOS 12.1 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

19) In IntelliJ, clicked the "Run" green arrow icon in the upper right. After program build completed, checked Firebase install web page a received confirmation message "Congratulations, you've successfully added Firebase to your app!"

**Following these steps, connection between app and Firebase appears to be functioning properly.**